# Setting time input with jquery does not work in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have a simple html code that sets the value of input of type time in document ready function. it works in computer browser correctly. but it does not work in mobile devices.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="time" id="time" style="height:25px">

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
   $("#time").attr("value","23:30");
  });
  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

while raw javascript works perfectly (below code):

```html
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="time" id="time" style="height:25px">

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
   document.getElementById("time").value = "23:30";
  });
  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some search on Google and Mozilla has a great explanation about `<input type="time">`. some mobile browsers like Safari does not support this input yet.

> As mentioned above, Safari and a few other, less common, browsers don't yet support time inputs natively

### [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Handling_browser_support)

this code behaves like `time` input on my mobile phone. use `val` method instead `att`.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
            $("#time").val("23:30");
        });
```

let me know if this helps you.